# Android Resources converting to string TypedValue warning

Tags: android, resources

Ok I'm looking right past something here..

Every time I'm in my app and I change activities, logcat reports series of warnings:

```
02-04 14:42:36.524: WARN/Resources(1832): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08002b}
02-04 14:42:36.524: WARN/Resources(1832): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08002c}
02-04 14:42:36.524: WARN/Resources(1832): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f08002d}
```

Other apps are not showing such warnings.  Is this a pre-release/aapt compression thing?

Comment: Can you post some code showing how you are switching activities?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You are using a bool resource where a string is expected.

You can find which resource is being used incorrectly by opening your generated R.java file and searching for the resource IDs from the logcat message:

```
0x7f08002b
0x7f08002c
0x7f08002d
```

All three should be from your bool.xml file (the "t=0x12" in the warning message means the resources are [TYPE_INT_BOOLEAN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#TYPE_INT_BOOLEAN)).

Then, find where those resource IDs are being used in your project (probably a layout xml, but could be anywhere) and make sure the types match.

Here's an example of a TextView that would generate that log message.  If in my res/values/bool.xml I have:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="foo_flag">false</bool>
</resources>
```

I can incorrectly refer to it from a a layout xml file:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/foo"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@bool/foo_flag"></TextView>
```

When I run that app, I'll get the warning message since "text" expects a string resource, not a bool (my app appears as expected though since the flag is converted to the string "false").

**Updated for Android Gradle 4.X:**

As of sometime by version 4.0.1 of the Android grade plugin this has changed.  An `R.java` file is no longer generated.  Instead An `R.txt` file is generated located somewhere like:

```
    build/intermediates/runtime_symbol_list/{variant}/R.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Mike!  Turned out not to be a bool resource, but checking the resource IDs was the bump I needed.  I had android:text="@id/foo" - an integer @id in my TextView text field.

Comment: Interestingly, my environment (Eclipse with MOTODEV) defaults TextView text fields to have the same content as their id fields.  It's nice to see the ids in the layout, but results in these warnings at runtime.  No doubt there is a (minor?) performance penalty for the converts as well.

Comment: For me it wasn't the boolean stuff either but just like DJC said a text="@id/foo" somewhere. Thanks for the helping entry!

Comment: Very cool, but the new version of Android Studio no longer makes R.java files!  Yikes!  Now what to do?

Comment: @smbiggs - see my recent edit.  It's now `build/intermediates/runtime_symbol_list/$variant/R.txt`

Answer (score 61):

These warnings only occurred when a certain **developer option** was enabled.

> Device Settings > Developer options > Disable 'Enable view attribute inspection'

Comment: @user1281750 Perfect, I did indeed have that option set.

Comment: This option is enabled and disabled in your device settings, not in Eclipse or Android Studio

Comment: [Another user entered a bug report](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26853964/868173) related to this issue.

Comment: samething happen me :)

Comment: Kind of hard-handed solution, but works.  I'd really like to know WHY the device thinks these are warnings though!

Answer (score 3):

I've discovered that this warning is also outputted when specifying a plurals string from a widget that requires parameters.

For instance:

```
<plurals name="song_count">
    <item quantity="one">%d song in playlist</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d songs in playlist</item>
</plurals>
```

The warning will appear when inflating an activity that contains a widget referencing it:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_total_songs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@plurals/song_count" />
```

You no doubt replace the string after inflating the views to set the correct parameters, e.g.:

```
playlistSongCount.setText(
        getResources().getQuantityString(
            R.plurals.song_count,
            songCount,
            songCount));
```

The obvious solution here is to remove the `android:text` attribute from the layout as it has no purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if you don't have:-

```
<TextView android:text="@+id/labelText"/>
```

in your resource file.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in `android:text="@+id/fooText`

Try change in your .xml this:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/foo" 
    android:text="@+id/fooText"/>
```

To this:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/foo" 
    android:text=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in `ListPreference` default value. Even if you type it as `String` (for example `"10"`) it will be interpreted as `int` and then converted to `String` and thus complaining.

For example, this will give a warning:

```
<ListPreference
     android:defaultValue="10"
     ...
/>
```

but this will not:

```
<ListPreference
     android:defaultValue="@string/ten"
     ...
/>
```

and define `@string/ten` in `strings.xml` as:

```
<string name="ten" translatable="false">10</string>
```

Dumb, but it gets rid of the warning.