# why logcat show WARN/Resources(1865): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0?

Tags: android, android-logcat

i have spinner in dialog box , when i select value from spinner log cat show the below message..

```
06-22 12:42:48.941: WARN/Resources(1865): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090290}

06-22 12:42:48.991: WARN/Resources(1865): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090290}

06-22 12:42:50.471: WARN/Resources(1865): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090290}

06-22 12:42:50.520: WARN/Resources(1865): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090290}

06-22 12:42:50.540: WARN/Resources(1865): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090290}

06-22 12:42:50.550: WARN/Resources(1865): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090290}

06-22 12:42:50.561: WARN/Resources(1865): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090290}

06-22 12:42:50.571: WARN/Resources(1865): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090290}

06-22 12:42:50.580: WARN/Resources(1865): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090290}

06-22 12:42:50.590: WARN/Resources(1865): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090290}

06-22 12:42:52.221: WARN/Resources(1865): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090290}

06-22 12:42:52.301: WARN/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44ed5cc0
```

what is this messages show?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Resources converting to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903948/android-resources-converting-to-string)

Answer (score 2):

The WARN message shows r=0x7f090290 therefore in your generated R.java,
you should find 0x7f090290 and the issue should be related to the variables
near the number. I guess you need to change string <-> integer in resource xml.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Developer Options**-> "**Enable view attribute inspection**" Uncheck this option solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Often you'll search your R.java file, and find the item that is causing the problem (0x7f090290, in your case)... and find the matching variable name.   But there's no quick way to use Eclipse to find where that item is be used.  It could be in countless files somewhere.  And (in my case) it doesn't really exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `android:text="@+id/fooText`

Try change in your **XML** as following:

```
 <TextView 
android:id="@+id/foo" 
android:text="@+id/fooText"/>
```

To this:

```
    <TextView 
android:id="@+id/foo" 
android:text=""/>
```

Comment: Not sure how you can say that, provided that the xml file is not posted