# Android - Logcats are full of "Converting to boolean" "res/anim/overshoot_interpolator.xml"

Tags: android, xml, animation

I'm using an animation to fill my list view and I see this line 100's of times in my logcat -

`Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x326 "res/anim/overshoot_interpolator.xml" a=1 r=0x10a0008}`

Here is my animation xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator">
    <translate

        android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="100" android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="400" />


    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="400"
        />

</set>
```

And here is the java code

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
/* work done to set content for the view elements
*/
 // if user is scrolling down
 if(cursor.getPosition() > lastPosition){
      view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.up_from_bottom));
   }
        lastPosition = cursor.getPosition(); // set lastPostion to this one
}
```

I'm afraid that on a weaker device my app might crash or something... It seems like something is supposed to be a boolean, but I have no clue what it is.

Has anybody ever seen this? Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903948/android-resources-converting-to-string read it

Comment: I read that. It doesn't help me though... I have any strings here and I don't know where the Boolean is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use android:shareInterpolator="(boolean value false or true)" instead of android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"
For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate

        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="400" />


    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="400"
        />

</set>
```