# Android animation resources warning: converting to boolean

Tags: android, android-animation, android-resources

I recently observed some warnings in logcat for my test app and I have searched it in Google, but it seems there is no much clue. I also checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903948/android-resources-converting-to-string), but unfortunately it does not clear my confusion.

Here is a full warning message:

```
08-28 11:03:13.125: W/Resources(11409): Converting to boolean: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x1422 "res/anim/decelerate_interpolator.xml" a=1 r=0x10a0006}
```

I have searched in both generated R.java (one in my package, the other in appcompat v7 package) for 0x10a0006, but no result.

I used decelerate_interpolator in some of my animation files. and if I do not use this, no such warning would appear in logcat.

I appreciate your help!